# postgres stored procedure to update multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.4

I am writing a stored procedure to update multiple table's data in Postgres 9.4. I will execute this procedure from python.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_data(
    list_table_name TEXT[],
    list_parameters TEXT[]
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER AS $$

BEGIN
FOR i IN list_table_name LOOP
  FOR j IN dict_parameters LOOP
    EXECUTE '
   UPDATE ' || i || '
   SET    default_value = ' || j.param_val || '
   WHERE  ' || i.id = j.id ||''
  END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
-- dict_parameters would be python list of dictionary [{"id":val,"param_val":[val1,val2,val3]},{"id":val,"param_val":[val1,val2,val3]}]
-- list_table_name would be python list containing table names.
```

First of all this gives me error as -

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 8: BEGIN
        ^
optimation=# END LOOP;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LOOP"
LINE 1: END LOOP;
            ^
```

And even if it runs I am not sure if I am extracting the values the right way. If someone could guide me.

Comment: Possible SQL Injection.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY  also: you declare a parameter named `list_parameters` but use a parameter named `dict_parameters`

Comment: Changed dict_parameters to list_parameters and I have it in my mind to  filter input to prevent sql injection once this code runs properly. Still errors are same.